# The current path, {% didn't match any of these django responsive images

Tags: html, css, django, responsive

I keep getting this error when the browser width size is below 640px and above 990px. I am trying to display different resolution images depending on the browser width size.

`The current path, about/{%, didn't match any of these.`

In other words the only image that displays properly is `footer-city-medium.jpg`

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %} {% load static %}

<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:990px)" srcset={% static '/images/footer-city-large.jpg' %}> 
  <source media="(min-width:640px)" srcset={% static '/images/footer-city-medium.jpg' %}>
  <img src={% static '/images/footer-city-small.jpg' %}>
</picture>

{% endblock %}
```

The page renders properly except for the image. Only the `footer-city-medium.jpg` renders in properly.

Does the `source` attribute not work with django?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run collectstatic before using static tag?